# How to install latest version of Evince in my Xubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, installation, evince

I wish to install the latest version of Evince (3.18) in my Xubuntu 15.04 machine (64 bits), which comes with v. 3.14.2 installed.

I tried following the instructions from Evince's [web page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince/GettingEvince), using jhbuild, but with no success

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the PPA `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

And then issue

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install evince
```

Details [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/625151).

But beware! This can break your system. It almost did it to mine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have since moved to KDE, so I cannot test it.